# In ggplot, if I set a parameter for a geom, how do I make it appear in the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I make a specified parameter appear in the legend. I'm pretty sure I've seen this done via a simple parameter or function, and I think it's pretty recent in ggplot.

```
ggplot(data) + 
     geom_point(aes(x=foo, y=foo), color='red') +
     geom_point(aes(x=bar, y=bar), color='blue')
```

How can I make red and blue appear as keys in the legend?

Comment: move them into the `aes` within the `geom`

Comment: Define the color values inside aes and use scale_color_manual to define the colors. ggplot2 only creates legends for variables mapped in the aestetics mapping.

Comment: That did it. I knew it was something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick example with the `mtcars` dataset. We use `aes` to define colors based on a character value, then use `scale_colour_manual` to specify.

```
ggplot(mtcars)+
    geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = 'wt'))+
    geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = drat, colour = 'drat'))+
    scale_colour_manual(values = c('wt' = 'blue','drat' = 'red'))
```

[image]