# R showing different regression lines in a ggplot key

Tags: r, key, linear-regression, tidy

I'm trying to plot different simple linear regression estimates on the same coordinate plane to understand something of the differences between different methods. But my question is about adding these lines in R code and not about the statistics of the differences lines.

Here I'm using the *mtcars* dataset. And I'm using the `mblm` and `quantreq` packages to come up with different regression equations or, more specifically, the parameters for the slope and intercept for different simple linear regression estimates.

The OLS estimate I add using the `geom_smooth()` function and specifying the `method` argument. I could add the slope and intercept using geom_abline() after creating a linear model object; that's another option.

The Theil-Sen and median least squares deviation estimates I'm creating a model first for each using the respective packages. Then I'm adding the slope and intercept using `geom_abline()`.

So now I've added the lines manually. But how can I create a key or legend in `ggplot` to show these different lines? `ggplot()` adds the key automatically when `geom_smooth()` is separated into different groups. But I don't think it adds a legend for geom_abline. And anyway my plot uses a mixture of both. Any ideas? I've never had to add more own key in this way.

```
library(mblm)
ts_fit <- mblm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

library(quantreg)
lad_fit <- rq(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  labs(subtitle = "Simple Linear Regressions") +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE, color = '#376795') +
  geom_abline(intercept = coef(ts_fit)[1], slope = coef(ts_fit)[2], color = '#f7aa58', size = 1) +
  geom_abline(intercept = coef(lad_fit)[1], slope = coef(lad_fit)[2], color = '#72bcd5', size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I searched SO on: “[r] make legend ggplot”.  See if this answers the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442750/in-ggplot-if-i-set-a-parameter-for-a-geom-how-do-i-make-it-appear-in-the-legen

Comment: Thanks for quick response - I had additional trouble with the legend (sometimes it listed the color chosen instead of the model... I think I kept doing additional things wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding a separate geom for each model, I would create a dataframe including the intercept and slope for all models. Then you can pass this to a single `geom_abline()` and map `color` to the different models.

Note, I don't have {mblm} or {quantreg} installed, so I ran `lm()` on different subsets of `mtcars` as an approximation.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create dataframe with model coefficients
models <- data.frame(
    lm = coef(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars[1:20,])),
    ts = coef(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars[7:26,])),
    lad = coef(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars[11:32,]))
  ) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "model") %>% 
  rename_with(~ c("model", "intercept", "slope"))

models
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   model intercept slope
#   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 lm         38.5 -5.41
# 2 ts         38.9 -5.59
# 3 lad        37.6 -5.41

# specify ggplot, passing `mtcars` to `geom_point()` and `models` to `geom_abline()`
ggplot() + 
  labs(subtitle = "Simple Linear Regressions") +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_abline(
    data = models, 
    aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, color = model),
    size = 1
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This works - thanks for the strategy. I'll edit your comment to include the result on my end

Comment: what does the t() function by itself do and why is it used in this context?

Comment: `t()` is transpose. Transposing "flips a matrix over its diagonal; that is, it switches the row and column indices" (per wikipedia). Here. the `models` df starts out with models in columns and parameters in rows, but we need it the other way round -- so we transpose it.